# Using getCanonicalName in static method of a class

Tags: java

I have a class with a static method.

In that static method, I require the canonical name of the class containing that method. (I'd rather not hardcode it).

An obvious way would be to use `this.getClass().getCanonicalName();` but, of course, I can't do this in a `static` function since `this` is meaningless.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
YourClassName.class.getCanonicalName();
```

this is what you want, considering this:

```
public class YourClassName {

    public static void doSomething() {

        YourClassName.class.getCanonicalName();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to call 
       (ClassName).class.getCanonicalName();